# How to save p = scatterplot(data1~data2] in R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to save a scatterplot in a variable in R?
Everytime I do this:

```
library(car)
data1=as.numeric(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=1))
data2=as.numeric(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=1))
p <- scatterplot(data1 ~ data2)
```

I get p = NULL

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a data sample of `data1` and `data2` using `dput`. Plus, from which package does `scatterplot()` come?

Comment: @MonJeanJean From package `car`. To the OP: see the Value section and the 7th ( 3rd from last) and last examples in `help("scatterplot")`.

Comment: Apologies. Now edited.

Comment: @RuiBarradas "If points are identified, their labels are returned; otherwise NULL is returned invisibly" What does this mean?

Comment: I understand now. If I add id = TRUE, it will return some value, however, I was aiming at storing the whole plot as with ggplot, in a variable.

Comment: That is not possible, the function only returns the points that are within a Mahalanobis distance from the center of the data or identified by clicking on them (last example).

Comment: So I understand that p <- saving plot is only possible with certain plotting functions.